# calling webservice within another webservice

Tags: .net, ssl, .net-core

Web service A is developed in the classic .NET Framework 4.6.1 and web service B is developed in .netcore 3.1.

Web service A is trying to consume Web service B but throws an error "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

I used postman to consume webservice b and was successfull
created console application to consume web service b and was successful.

here is an example

This is developed using .netCore3.1

```
namespace WebServiceBNetCore.Controllers
{
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController: ControllerBase
{
[HttpPost, Route("NetCoreEndpoint")]
public string test([FromBody]AssignModel model)
{
return string.Format("you entered {0}",model.Value);
}
}
public class AssignModel
{
public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

calling it from postman returns the desired output.
http://localhost:5000/test/NetCoreEndpoint

```
{"Value": "9"}
```

The following webservice is developed with .net framework 4.6.1

```
namespace WcfServiceREST
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Test")]
string GetDataFromMeAndNetCoreWS(int value);
}
}

namespace WcfServiceREST
{
public class Service1 : IService1
{
public string GetDataFromMeAndNetCoreWS(int value)
{
string mydata  = string.Format("You entered: {0} in classic .Net 4.6.1", value);
string json = "{\"Value\": \"9\"}";
string netcoreData = PostToRESTfulService("http://localhost:5000/test/NetCoreEndpoint", json­­);
return (mydata + netcoreData);
}

private string PostToRESTfulService(string address, string 
jsonParameters, bool do_app_json = false, bool acceptHeaderAsXML = false)
{
    string response;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);
    request.Method = "POST";

    if (do_app_json)
    {
        request.ContentType = @"application/json";
    }
    else
    {
        request.ContentType = @"text/json; charset=utf-8";
    }
    if (acceptHeaderAsXML)
    {
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
    }
    request.Timeout = 3600000;// 1 hour
    try
    {
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = jsonParameters;
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); <------error occurs here 
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Response != null)
        {
            string error = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            throw new WebException(error, ex);
        }
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return response;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Enigmativity I updated the descrioption to include a reproducable exmple

Comment: Sorry, you say that you're calling one webservice from within another, but your code and your example only show one webservice. Can you show the correct code? Also, you need to say where the error is occurring.

Comment: @Enigmativity, sorry i just included the endpoint from each webservice, I updated the description to include the full code....sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was staring at me. on my local environment   not valid certificate was installed and my .net core prohect configurtion is to forward all http request to HTTPS. hope this helps someone else